# jCrop: Set a square selection (centred) of an uploaded image of any dimensions

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I would like to offer my users the ability to crop their uploaded image via jCrop.  The result should be a square format.  The selection should appear centred in the image, with about a 10% gap either side along the shortest dimension.  Current code:

```
        jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#imgCrop', {
            onSelect:    storeCoords,
            onChange:    storeCoords,
            aspectRatio: 1
            setSelect:   [20, 20, 280, 280]
        });
```

so rather than hardcoded values I need a way to set the x1, y1, x2, y2 values to the correct positions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the coordinates from your [preview method](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/issues/50) as parameters for the array:

```
 jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#imgCrop', {
        onSelect:    storeCoords,
        onChange:    storeCoords,
        aspectRatio: 1
        setSelect:   [ ($('#imgCrop').attr('width') / 2) - 10, 
                       ($('#imgCrop').attr('height') / 2) - 10, 
                       ($('#imgCrop').attr('width') / 2) + 10, 
                       ($('#imgCrop').attr('height') / 2) + 10 
                     ]
        });
```

It will take some trial and error to find the pattern and get it to work consistently.